# The "php" plugin does not exist

Tags: 8

I got this error after migrating from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8.1.3.

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "php" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DiscoveryTrait.php).

How can I fix this error?

Comment: have you checked log files on the server?

Comment: that's exactly what the log say. it also display that same message on my web page.

Comment: it is on all pages? have you got blank page with this error?

Comment: that shows me in the user/login page only. Front end shows site under maintenance.

Comment: This most likely shows up when viewing content that is configured to display a text format that had php plugin enabled previously. I needed to re-save all of my text formats after migrating from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do these actions in your database :

1. Locate php_code in 'node_revision_body' table at
   'body_format' column, and change it from 'php_code' to
   'filtered_html'.
2. There is also 'filter.format.php_code' in my config table, i delete that.
3. `drush cr`.
4. Enable 'php' module from drush using the command 'drush pm-enable php'.

Answer (score 2):

It's a guess, but the php module was removed from core in D8 and is now supplied by a contrib module: [PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/php)

You will need to install it additionally.

---

**Edit 1:**

If you don't intend to use the module in the future, enable it only temporarily, find alternatives for the fields/text formates currently using it (if needed, the filter may be available but not actually used for php) then uninstall it again once you are done.

Comment: is there anyway that i can removed this module entry/reference from database directly?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Personally I would enable it, find all places were the php filter was enabled/used find an alternative that works for your purpose and uninstall php module again.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't access admin page anymore as i got that error message on user/login

Comment: While I don't know how to remove the php options from fields in the db, you can try to enable the php module manually in the db: https://www.drupal.org/node/157632